# Error Configuring Oracle Database during SAP ERP installation

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sap-erp

I am attempting to install SAP ERP on LINUX vm. After successfully installing Oracle Database when I return to SAP installation, it fails in executing the following command to setup oracle service on a network.

```
lsnrctl start
```

It appears to be a permission issue. However, I cant seem to figure out under which user the SAP installation is running.

Attached is the screenshot of error:

> Log files are written to <path>
>
> [image]

Comment: did you follow the installation manual for your SAP release? The database itself should, if I remember correctly, be installed as ora<sid> and the oracle directories need the appropriate permissions. The manual has extensive documentation about the file system permissions. What does the installation log file contain? Check permissions for /oracle and the subdirectories. Also check if the SAP users <sid>adm and ora<sid> are in the operating system groups (sapsys, dba etc.) they should be in.

Comment: Dirk,  thank you for the reply. I suspect that it is permissions issue because if I execute lsnrctl start as root it works however, the SAP installation doesnt seem to use the started service.  If you can point me to some online documentation that would help me set permissions on SAP users

Comment: you can get the installation manuals at http://service.sap.com/erp-inst . A user account at sap.com is mandatory, afaik the manuals are not available to the general public. There is a generic master guide for the product (e.g. SAP ERP) and a specific install guide for your enviroment (here for instance Netweaver 7.0, Linux x86/64 / Oracle, Abap, Java or Abap+Java)